# CSS3 transition only works once

Tags: html, css, typescript, angular5

I need to animate a refresh icon to rotate it when clicking it. I found a way to do it through CSS.

css file

```
.refresh:focus .mat-icon {
  animation: rotate 2s ease-in-out;
}

@keyframes rotate {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
```

html file

```
              <button mat-icon-button class="refresh" color="primary" (click)="refreshTableFkeys()">
                <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">refresh</mat-icon>
              </button>
              <button mat-icon-button color="primary" (click)="addNewFkey()">
                <mat-icon aria-label="Example icon-button with a heart icon">add</mat-icon>
              </button>
```

When I click the button, the icon rotates once. When I click it again to refresh again, the animation stops working. How do I make the animation trigger in every click?

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
typescript

```
  refreshTableFkeys() {
    this.dataSource_Fkeys.paginator._changePageSize(this.dataSource_Fkeys.paginator.pageSize);
  }
```

Comment: I'd say the first easy choice is to change the `:focus` pseudo-class to an `:active` one; but that might also give you a different result

Comment: I had the same result. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @GonçaloReis add your javascript for refreshTableFkeys. Also you have an end tag (mat-header-cell?) without a matching start tag in your code

Comment: @RachelGallen the end tag was not supposed to be copied. I just added Type script, but it's not related to this issue. Maybe I can add something related to the animation to make it work, in that method. Any suggestion?

Comment: @GonçaloReis there's not  a lot in the question to go on. Have you tried removing the :focus / replacing it with :active? A running example would help (jsfiddle.net/codepen) By the way the code you added is not named the same as the function named previously in your code